# ASP Classic IPN listener worked and now doesn't

Tags: asp-classic, paypal-ipn

I have had this code working for 6 months.  Now, it stopped working. I have spent 2 days on PayPal support, Stackoverflow q/a, Google... I hope honestly this isn't a repeat question but I have searched truthfully for 2 days on Stackoverflow and haven't found an answer.

With local testing it produces a 200 answer and INVALID which is perfect for the sandbox.  When I go to the IPN Simulator on PayPal it always returns red. Help me Obi Wan Kanobi => You're my only hope! Thank you for any help possible.

My reduced code is:

```
   paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"

   strResponse = "cmd=_notify-validate&" & Request.Form

   set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")  
   objHttp.open "POST", paypal_url, false  
   objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  
   objHttp.Send strResponse

   if (objHttp.status <> 200 ) then  
      str = "ERROR 200"  
   elseif (objHttp.responseText = "VERIFIED") then  
      str = "VERIFIED"  
   elseif (objHttp.responseText = "INVALID") then  
      str = "INVALID"  
   else  
      str = "ERROR GENERAL"  
   end if  

   set objHttp = nothing
```

Comment: No promises, but try `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`

Comment: Also, there's an Experts Exchange question which might be relevant.  https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28937989/Msxml2-ServerXMLHTTP-6-0-not-using-TLS1-2-in-Windows-Server-2012.html

Comment: I think there may be a problem with the IPN simulator.  I notice that if I put in a non existent URL I get the same IPN not sent error.  Look at your web log to see if you are getting anything from sandbox.paypal.com.  It may not be sending you anything!  Also, have you tried doing a test payment (sandbox.paypal.com) or actual payment (paypal.com) and see if you get IPN message to your listener.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the IPN simulator isn't working. I created a script with this

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    ini_set('error_log', 'ipn_errors.log');
    $fp = fopen('.log', "a");
    fwrite($fp, date("\tY-m-d H:i:s") . "\n");
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
        fwrite($fp, "$key\t$value\n");
    }
    fwrite($fp, "--\n");
    fclose($fp);

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
?>
```

and pointed the IPN simulator to it. It is not writing to .log, it is not being called.